# Error during SonarScanner execution after executing SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end command

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarqube-7.9

Sonarqube Version -7.9.5

SonarQube Scanner - sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.0.4.24009-net46

Source code contains - C#, angular.js, html5, javascript.

Hi,

I executed the following commands and after executing the 3rd command I am getting execution failure error.

The command I executed in the CMD prompt are browsing to the path where solution is present are,

1. SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"Demo" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="TokenID_ABC"
2. MsBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
3. SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="TokenID_ABC"

**ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution**
**org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property**

[image]

I found one similar kind of issue reported where it is said that due to .java file present in the code the issue occurs, in our code as well .java files are present, not sure the use of them. How can I exclude those .java files while SonarQube analysis is performed and in which file do I need to add exclusion code?

Also, if there is some another solution to resolve this issue, then please let me know as I have very limited knowledge of Sonar.

Link of similar issue -
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/error-while-running-sonar-scanner-please-provide-compiled-classes-of-your-project-with-sonar-java-binaries-property/30027/2

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude arbitrary files by going to your project settings in SonarQube -> Analysis Scope -> Source File Exclusions. Use regex to match your java files, i.e. `*.java`.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Got the same error. In cmd prompt log it does show's Excluded sources: *.java in the log but I still get the same error. I also tried deleting the *.java files to make sure that the error is due to the java files and after deleting java file executed above 3 commands and it worked. Not sure how can I exclude them without deleting them. There must be another way.